# cors headers whitelist for ios and android apps

Tags: android, ios, django, cors, django-cors-headers

I am a newbie for IOS and Android App Development and I am seeking knowledge. I have a Django web API that has a configuration of

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('example1.com', 'example2.com')
```

I'm aware that only apps in the hostname of these 2 are the requests that my web API will accept but my question is.. What about IOS and Android apps that I am going to build to connect to my web API. Will those also be blocked?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the problem, but if you use the OAuth to consume the API it should fix your problem, so you always know the clients and you know if they can have the access to your API

Comment: Ok let's consider using Oauth, and put these two hostnames(('example1.com', 'example2.com')) in the redirect_uri, will the requests coming from the IOS app I made be allowed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cors is enforced by web browsers. If you are writing code that does not run in a browser (or a browser engine), cors is completely ignored unless you specifically implement it yourself (by making a prior OPTIONS HTTP call).